# Bigquery Window Id

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to create a new column with the id of the first record inside the window.
For a table like this:

```
uniqueId | position
-------------------
      01 | First
      02 | Last 
      03 | First
      04 | Cont 
      05 | Cont 
      06 | Cont 
      07 | Cont 
      08 | Cont 
      09 | Cont 
      10 | Last 
      11 | First
      12 | Cont 
      13 | Cont 
      14 | Cont 
      15 | Last 
      16 | First
      17 | Cont 
      18 | Last
```

This is the expected result:

```
uniqueId | position | result
----------------------------
      01 | First    | 01
      02 | Last     | 01
      03 | First    | 03
      04 | Cont     | 03
      05 | Cont     | 03
      06 | Cont     | 03
      07 | Cont     | 03
      08 | Cont     | 03
      09 | Cont     | 03
      10 | Last     | 03
      11 | First    | 11
      12 | Cont     | 11
      13 | Cont     | 11
      14 | Cont     | 11
      15 | Last     | 11
      16 | First    | 16
      17 | Cont     | 16
      18 | Last     | 16
```

I've tried several different approches using BQ's window funcions, but no luck =/

> Help me ObiWan Kenobi, You're my only hope.

Comment: Hi Augusto, Can you please explain with more details about how you want to calculate the value of the field result. Why on the 1st-row result is 01 and also on the 2nd row and then on the 3rd you expect to get 03

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT uniqueId, position, 
  FIRST_VALUE(uniqueId) OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY IF(position = 'First', 0, 1)) result
FROM (
  SELECT uniqueId, position, 
    COUNTIF(position = 'First') OVER(ORDER BY CAST(uniqueId AS INT64)) grp
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from ytour question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '01' uniqueId, 'First' position UNION ALL
  SELECT '02', 'Last ' UNION ALL
  SELECT '03', 'First' UNION ALL
  SELECT '04', 'Cont ' UNION ALL
  SELECT '05', 'Cont ' UNION ALL
  SELECT '06', 'Cont ' UNION ALL
  SELECT '07', 'Cont ' UNION ALL
  SELECT '08', 'Cont ' UNION ALL
  SELECT '09', 'Cont ' UNION ALL
  SELECT '10', 'Last ' UNION ALL
  SELECT '11', 'First' UNION ALL
  SELECT '12', 'Cont ' UNION ALL
  SELECT '13', 'Cont ' UNION ALL
  SELECT '14', 'Cont ' UNION ALL
  SELECT '15', 'Last ' UNION ALL
  SELECT '16', 'First' UNION ALL
  SELECT '17', 'Cont ' UNION ALL
  SELECT '18', 'Last ' 
)
SELECT uniqueId, position, 
  FIRST_VALUE(uniqueId) OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY IF(position = 'First', 0, 1)) result
FROM (
  SELECT uniqueId, position, 
    COUNTIF(position = 'First') OVER(ORDER BY CAST(uniqueId AS INT64)) grp
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
-- ORDER BY uniqueId
```

with result

```
Row uniqueId    position    result   
1   01          First       01   
2   02          Last        01   
3   03          First       03   
4   04          Cont        03   
5   05          Cont        03   
6   06          Cont        03   
7   07          Cont        03   
8   08          Cont        03   
9   09          Cont        03   
10  10          Last        03   
11  11          First       11   
12  12          Cont        11   
13  13          Cont        11   
14  14          Cont        11   
15  15          Last        11   
16  16          First       16   
17  17          Cont        16   
18  18          Last        16
```